# How to speed up name extraction in removing

Tags: r, regex

Here is a example and solution I'm using in getting rid of `\r\n` and extracting only the name and short sign after name either i.e. or e.g. or f.s.g. etc.

This example and solution works for me but it is slow. I have hundred of thousands rows like this.

```
x <- "yyy XXX i.e.\r\n            \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n  INFO: 12235041 \r\n        \r\n            \r\n"

do.call(rbind, lapply(1:length(x), function(i) strsplit(gsub('[\n\r]',' ',x),"   ")[[i]][1]))
```

Comment: Are the line breaks consistent in your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to use a regex, split with `\r\n` fixed string and get the first element:

```
x <- "yyy XXX i.e.\r\n            \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n  INFO: 12235041 \r\n        \r\n            \r\n"
strsplit(x, "\r\n", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/z1W4hJ)

If the line break style is not consistent in your data, you may use a regex replacement like

```
sub("[\r\n].*", "",x)
```

where `[\r\n]` matches either `\r` or `\n`, then `.*` matches any 0+ chars and this match is removed with `sub`. The same can be achieved with `regmatches` and a `^[^\r\n]+` regex that matches 1+ chars other than CR and LF at the start of the string:

```
unlist(regmatches(x, regexpr("^[^\r\n]+", x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("\r\n.*", "", x)
#[1] "yyy XXX i.e."
```

Comment: Yup...ah well... have a nice day anyway

Comment: @Sotos Same to you as well.